# How to save user inputed data c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I wanted to know how to save user inputed data. Like when they type in a text box or check a checkbox and close the application the next time they start it up again, that data that they inputed is there like saved. this is in c# VS2010 .NET 4.0

Comment: It would be a good idea to state where you want to save it i.e. sql database, .config user settings, xml, etc.

Comment: Under UserSettings, I already have it added to my form

Comment: Define `UserSettings`. Is it a custom control, a helper class or something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UserSettings.aspx)?

Comment: It will save under the .config user settings file i believe so. I am only 16, I am learning, I don't know that much about this stuff just yet.

Answer (score 1):

In the project settings you can add settings, then add an event lister for the FormClosing event.

In that you can put

```
MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting = MyTxtBox.Text;
MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the user input into the any database or in [app.config](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/07/13/879.aspx) or in [xml](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/readwritexmltutmellli2111282005041517am/readwritexmltutmellli21.aspx) files, so that the next file you start the application you can read the values from there.